# Getting a "TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'" in a client -> server chat program

Tags: python-3.x, sockets

I'm trying to create a chat program for an assignment in python3.8.1 . My code uses a client script and then a server script, that I run in separate terminal windows. I run the server script first. It runs and then hangs waiting for a connection. I then run the client script. The following error is then produced in the server script.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "server-chat.py", line 19, in <module>
    connect.sendall("You are connected from:" + str(addr))
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

My code for the client is below:

```
import socket
client_socket = socket.socket()
port = 12345
client_socket.connect(('127.0.0.1',port))

recv_msg = client_socket.recv(1024)
print (recv_msg)

send_msg = input("Enter your username (prefix with #): ")
client_socket.send(send_msg)

while True:
    recv_msg = client_socket.recv(1024)
    print (recv_msg)
    send_msg = input("Send your message in format [@user:message] ")
    if send_msg == 'exit':
        break
    else:
        client_socket.send(send_msg)

client_socket.close()
```

My code for the server is below:

```
import socket
import select

port = 12345
socket_list = []
users = {}
server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
server_socket.bind(('', port))
server_socket.listen(5)
socket_list.append(server_socket)
while True:
    ready_to_read, ready_to_write, in_error = select.select(
        socket_list, [], [], 0)
    for sock in ready_to_read:
        if sock == server_socket:
            connect, addr = server_socket.accept()
            socket_list.append(connect)
            connect.sendall("You are connected from:" + str(addr))
        else:
            try:
                data = sock.recv(2048)
                if data.startswith("#"):
                    users[data[1:].lower()] = connect
                    print ("User " + data[1:] + " added.")
                    connect.send("Your user detail saved as : "+str(data[1:]))
                elif data.startswith("@"):
                    users[data[1:data.index(':')].lower()].send(
                        data[data.index(':')+1:])
            except:
                continue

server_socket.close()
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

`.send()` and `.recv()` take byte strings, but `input()` returns Unicode strings.  You must `.encode()` Unicode strings to byte strings to send them to a socket/pipe/file/etc.  Once received, `.decode()` the byte string back to a Unicode string at the other end.

The default encoding is `utf8` which can handle any Unicode code point, but you can specify other encodings if desired.

For more on Unicode, see [Pragmatic Unicode](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html).